# how to record the pcm device from the terminal in linux?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I want to record the pcm sound output from a terminal, and besides compress at the same time to mp3 or ogg instead of dumping a wave file.

Thanks

Comment: `man parecord` (Pulseaudio), `man arecord` (ALSA), use a pipe to feed to encoder of your choice. You may have to use raw format or `au` instead of `wav` (`wav` contains total length in header). What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Alternatively: let encoder of your choice input directly from ALSA or Pulseaudio device, if supported by the encoder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of alternatives:

**Pipe arecord to lame encoder (or any encoder of your choice):**

for example:

```
arecord -v -f cd -t raw | lame -r -b 192 - output.mp3
```

**Use ffmpeg:**

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 160k -i pulse -acodec libmp3lame OUTPUT.mp3
```

**Use Sox's "rec" utility:**

```
rec -c 2  myFile.mp3
```

More examples to take a look at:
http://mocha.freeshell.org/audio.html